# angular 2 bootstrap responsive doesn't work

Tags: angular, responsive-design

I work with Angular 2 and bootstrap. I want to do a responsive layout with the followed design. I use browser chrome

[image]

I have the below template.html

```
<div class="col-xs-2" [ngClass]="getClassesByPosition(0)">
    The first product is {{getProductByPosition(0).name}}.
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2" [ngClass]="getClassesByPosition(1)">
    The second product is {{getProductByPosition(1).name}}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of getTodoProducts(); let i = index">
            <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

When I resize the screen, responsive design doesn't work. This is the screen. In the chrome I don't see correctly the screen when I resize the chrome window

[image]

How can I see to fix this issue in the chrome?. Is it right my template.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because you are using col-xs-2 - this has the effect of creating the layout you have on every viewport size.

Bootstraps styling is based on min-width - and each column is 8.33% of its parent container width, meaning that if you specify col-xs-2 then you are effectively saying 16.66% of xs sized viewports AND UP.

What you need to do to get different layouts on different viewports is to provide a selection of sizes for the responsive layout: eg:

So lets say you want the following laoyut - the orange and blue divs to be sitting above the table on smaller screens, and on mobile screens (col-xs- you want to stack these two divs vertically - but in all other viewports - you want to have them horizontally and only on md and lg screens - have them beside the table.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2" [ngClass]="getClassesByPosition(0)">.../div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2" [ngClass]="getClassesByPosition(1)">...</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">...</div>
```

Also - incidentally - you have a typo in the table classes - its not table-stripped- but table -striped.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using col-xs- prefix. The columns won't stack up on resizing if you use that. Use **col-md or col-sm** to make it stack up (if that's your intention).